# How to make APC works in wampserver

Tags: php, wampserver, apc

I am using wampserver 2.2 locally. I have decided to enable APC PHP extension and server does not answer anymore. No request can go through (for css, javascript or whatever) or one or two sometimes.

in php.ini

```
extension=php_apc.dll

[APC]
apc.enabled=1
```

Is there anything else to do to make it work ?

Comment: do you have downloaded the package and then added it in the php.ini ?

Comment: yes I did... this is the code I show you

Comment: anything in the error log when you start the server?

Comment: No there is nothing in the error logs. it just turns on and on

Comment: What color is your Wampmanager icon when you activate APC i.e. is it green. If not then Apache has probably not started. What version of PHP are you using and did you download the matching version of the php_apc dll